# How can I check if a struct contains any data as I'm looping passed it?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, struct

I am trying to loop through a 2D array of structs that already have memory dynamically allocated for them and identify any structs that do not have data from user input.
In other words, I am asking a user to select specific spots withing the array to store their data and then I want to go through the array, printing everything in there, and displaying EMPTY for the spots that do not have data saved.

How can I determine if the struct contains data as I pass it in the loop?

```
typedef struct item {
    char name[20];
    int quantity;
} item;

struct item **shelves = (item **)malloc(num_rows * sizeof(item *));
for (i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
    shelves[i] = (item *)malloc(num_cols * sizeof(item));
}

for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < num_cols; j++) {
            ???     
    }               
}
```

Comment: Add a flag `bool empty;` to the structure.

Comment: `char empty` There is no `bool` type in C :p

Comment: @Avert Your information is outdated. Like about a decade, or so..

Comment: Unless every `struct` member is a string (`char` array) or a pointer, which are all initialised to `0` (which you can test), then you need another member - which also needs to be initialised.

Comment: Don't allocate an array of pointers. Just allocate an array of structures. This is far less messy and far faster.

Comment: @EugeneSh. some people still learn from the first edition of the K&R :)

Comment: Thanks all! Adding a bool variable works for what I needed. I will also try the calloc idea later as a separate version just to play around a bit I would like to keep the size of my array as small as possible. Cheers!

Comment: @MichalPatriak In order to save memory, you can add `bit field` of `1 bit` as a `flag` to check if the structure variable has value or it's empty.

Comment: @Mayur that will only save memory if there are other members which can also use a bit field, which does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: ..not speaking of the fact that it is most likely a very premature optimization.

Comment: @WeatherVane, another approach is like, after allocating memory to structure variable we can do `memset(shelves[i], 0, sizeof(item));`
To check if varible is empty or not we can do `if(!shelves[i][j].name[0]){ //variable is empty};`

Comment: @Mayur that is similar to my first comment.

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah, I just realized that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add a flag to mark used/empty structs.

Since C99 there is bool type using #include

Answer (score 0):

Add a flag to your struct `item`, and when the user specifies data for it then set the flag. You can use a `bool` like so:

```
typedef struct item {
    char name[20];
    int quantity;
    bool used;
} item;
```

or you could also use a bitfield:

```
typedef struct item {
    char name[20];
    int quantity;
    unsigned char used:1; //bitfield
} item;
```

Either way, set the `used` member to 1 (or `true` if its a `bool`) then check for it when printing the array of structs.

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < num_cols; j++) {
            if(shelves[i][j].used){
                //printf statement for struct goes here
            }
            else{
                //printf statement for EMPTY goes here
            }
    }               
}
```